# req.session.destroy() not working in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, express

Trying to perform logout operation by destroying session using **req.session.destroy()** in Nodejs but it is not working.

**Nodejs code:**

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  console.log(session.email);
  res.redirect('/signup');
});
```

I am calling /logout api from my html file.

**HTML CODE:-**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="row top text-center">
            <div class="col-md-2 righttopnav" >
                <a href="index" style="font-size:25px;">Auto<b>SecT</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <%if(session.email){%>
                <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a href="/signup">Signup / Login</a>
                <% } %>
                <a href="#career">Career</a>
                <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
                <a href="#services">Services</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section class="content">   
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 " >
                    <p class="p1"><%-session.email%>Scan your Website or APP with just a <b>click!</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="row text-center" style="padding-top:5%;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#c2c2a3"></i>
                <br>
                <input class="url" type="url"  placeholder="Enter your url" style="border-radius: 20px ">
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="p">OR</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#c2c2a3; padding-bottom: 4% "></i>
                <br>
                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  btn-file upload">
                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="file" style="display: none;">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="padding-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 1%; border-radius: 20%;">
                <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="Scan">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

/logout redirects me to the required page but session does not get destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

Please redirect once session destroy. 
You have to move your code for redirect in call back.

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.destroy(function(err){
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
     }else{
         console.log(session.email);
         req.end();
         res.redirect('/signup');
     }
  });

});
```

Comment: There must be some log

Comment: so what i have to do?

Comment: i am beginner in nodejs please help

Comment: Please can you share your repository

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.session = null; 
    res.redirect('/back/to/login');
});
```

Comment: This cause security issues, since the session is not destroyed!

Answer (score 1):

Try destroying session, and logging out:

```
 req.session.destroy();
 req.logout();
 res.redirect('/signup');
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

```
req.session.destroy(function () {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');              
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did two things and got it worked. First, I set unset to **destroy** in session options. Secondly, delete session as follows

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        delete req.session;
        res.redirect('/signup');
    });
```

ref https://github.com/expressjs/session

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `href` `<a href="/logout">Logout</a>` in logout.

Just create a `<p>` or `<button>`.

There is a conflict in your request.

Then, your `res.redirect('/signup');` should works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, earlier req.session.destroy was working fine but after updates it was not with passport and express-session. Having req.logout nested in req.session.destroy worked as others pointed out.

```js
const logout = async (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`unable to destroy session`, err);
    }
    if (!err) {
      req.logout((error) => {
        if (error) console.log(`unable to logout`, error);
      });
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  });
};
```